# reduce function gives negative answer

Tags: scala, apache-spark, reduce

Friends,

I'm trying to learn Scala coding and exploring the reduce() function as of now. I don't understand why the following piece of code to multiply all numbers in a list give me negative output:

```
    val inputRDD=sc.parallelize(List(1,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,19,22,21,25,34,56,4,32,56,70))

    val result=inputRDD.reduce((x,y)=>x*y)

    println(result)`
```

I get the answer "-1619001344" when i run the above code. If i try using "+" in reduce instead of "*" i get the proper sum, but not otherwise. I also tried converting result to Int, String and Long

Comment: Have you tried calculating the actual result? It's probably overflowing.

Comment: The product is 228235320014929920000 which doesn't fit in a 32 or 64 bit integer, so indeed overflows.

Comment: So if i still _did_ have to multiply all these numbers and return the result, would it be possible with some other data type or method?

Comment: I think scala has a BigInteger. They wrapped Java's I think.

Comment: Turns out even BigInt and BigDecimal dont suffice. Maybe my example isn't valid

Comment: Why? ...need more characters for the comment...

Comment: Map the list onto a list of BigInts and then parallelize and reduce. Or you could probably just pass a BigInt (1) as the seed value to `reduce`. Idk. I'm not at a computer.

Comment: Millie, the "map to BigInt" then "reduce" path worked :). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Int and Long types are both overflowing, so you need to use BigInt for this operation.

```
val inputRDD = sc.parallelize(List(1,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,19,22,21,25,34,56,4,32,56,70))

val inputRDDasBigInt = inputRDD.map(x => scala.BigInt(x))
val result = inputRDDasBigInt.reduce((x,y)=>x*y)

println(result)
228235320014929920000
```

Comment: thanks your example worked! I tweaked it a bit to use inputRDD.map(x => scala.BigInt(x)) without the toString and it shows the same result (in case that helps) :)